# Junit5 and Maven: @BeforeAll initialization method not being called

Tags: java, maven, junit5, maven-archetype, java-annotations

I would appreciate any hints as to why `@BeforeAll` is skipped in the following Junit5 test suite.  FYI, my output when I build with Maven:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

14:43:53.681 [main] DEBUG org.benthumb.db2_web_app.tests.CustomerDaoTest - creating test object...
Running org.benthumb.db2_web_app.tests.CustomerDaoTest

14:43:53.689 [main] DEBUG org.benthumb.db2_web_app.tests.CustomerDaoTest - test one executing...

14:43:53.696 [main] DEBUG org.benthumb.db2_web_app.tests.CustomerDaoTest - customer access object is null...
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 sec
```

```java
public class CustomerDaoTest {

    private static CustomerDao cDao;
    private static Customer cust;
    private static Properties props;
    private final static String PROP_FILE_NAME = "customer.properties";
    private static InputStream is;
    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomerDaoTest.class);

    public CustomerDaoTest() {
        logger.debug("creating test object...");
        is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(PROP_FILE_NAME);
    }

    @BeforeAll
    public static void initializeTestConditions() throws IOException {
        logger.debug("setting up customer access object...");
        props = new Properties();
        if (is != null) {
            props.load(is);
        } else {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + PROP_FILE_NAME + "' not found in the classpath");
        }

        cust = new Customer(
                props.getProperty("id"),
                props.getProperty("businessName"),
                props.getProperty("jobTitle"),
                props.getProperty("firstName"),
                props.getProperty("address"),
                props.getProperty("address2"),
                "",
                props.getProperty("city"),
                props.getProperty("state"),
                props.getProperty("country"),
                props.getProperty("phone")
        );
        cDao = new CustomerDao();
        //conn = cDao.conn;
    }

    @Test
    public void testConnectionCustomerDao() throws SQLException {
        //Properties prop = conn.getClientInfo();
        //assertEquals("these two values are equal", prop, null);
        logger.debug("test one executing...");
        Assumptions.assumeTrue(1 == 1);
    }

    @Test
    public void testPersistCustomerDao() {
        if (cDao != null) {
            try {
                cDao.addCustomer(cust);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                logger.error(Marker.ANY_MARKER, null, ex.getErrorCode());
            }
        } else {
            logger.debug("customer access object is null...");
        }
        Assumptions.assumeTrue(1 == 1);
    }

}
```

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that `BeforeAll` is not run? Is `cDao` null when the tests run?

Comment: does it have `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)` or no?

Comment: @user7, yes it's null.  Also, I can tell from logging output.

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo, no, I'm not using that annotation.  I'll try it--maybe it'll help.

Comment: @benthumb I have added it in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class doesn't have `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)` annotation. Add it and it will work fine.

Comment: Thank you.  FYI for anyone facing this issue: in order to make this work, in addition to junit-jupiter-api dependency, I had also had to add the following: 1) junit-platform-runner and 2) junit-jupiter-engine.

Comment: ˋRunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)ˋ is only needed on legacy platforms that do not support JUnit 5 out of the box. The original problem is probably due to the missing dependencies and/or using the wrong ˋ@Testˋ annotation.

Answer (score 1):

If you execute the unit tests with the maven lifecycle `test` the surefire plugin is used in the background. Depending on the version of the surefire plugin it supports different JUnit versions. Since surefire plugin version 3.0.0 JUnit 5 is supported out-of-the-box and no extra dependencies are necessary to execute JUnit 5 tests.

Prior version 3.0.0 it is necessary to add the junit-platform-runner and the `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)` so the JUnit 5 tests are executed with the right JUnit engine.